# list elements bottom alignment

Tags: html, css

I want to make 2 or more levels high tabs with `<li>` but make them grow from bottom to top. I have this

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li{
  margin: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but I need:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Is there a way to make it without js?

Comment: Yes, sort of,  check display flex property. But it may vary if the columns size varies based on multilevel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can reverse your `li` order I was able to get it working using a combination of `wrap-reverse` and `row-reverse` with `display: flex`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

li {
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply ad break line after third li element:

```
...
<li>3</li><br>
<li>4</li>
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li><br>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i guess you can try this.

Answer (score -1):

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li{
  margin: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <br/>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Just add a break